# Resizing height & width of the div in percentage not pixel by using angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular 5. I have to implement Resizing height & width of the div in percentage by using angular 5. Please help me to implement this functionality.

Comment: in your .ts percent:number=30; in the .html [style.height]="{{percent+%}}"

Comment: post your code. What you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this easily.

```
<p [style.width.%]="someValue"> ... </p>
<p [style.height.%]="someValue"> ... </p>
```

[**ref**](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3292-using-percent-for-in-line-styles-in-angular-4-2-3.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the css properties in .css file.

for example:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: powderblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you use it inside css/ .ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  styles: [`   
      .change-hight-width{
        height: 200px;
        width:200px;
      }   
  `]
//rest of the code
    })
```

in html

```
<div [ngClass]="'change-hight-width'">
```