# How to apply style with percentage in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

As per this [link](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/)

I can do

```
<p [style.width.px]="30">
  Some text that may be important.
</p>
```

This will set a width of 30 px.
How do I do the same for percentage ?

```
<p [style.width.percent]="30"> // This doesn't work
  Some text that may be important.
</p>
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey You know that AngularJS and Angular are world apart right ?

Comment: Yeah, guess I was thrown by the same answer... Here's a dupe for Angular: [Angular2 Bind Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31327596/215552) or [Resizing height & width of the div in percentage not pixel by using angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51494401/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey ya thats correct , you sent me a wrong link earlier

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You use the `%` symbol.

```
<p [style.width.%]="30">
```

You use what ever would normally come after the numeric value in CSS.

For example;

```
30rem => [style.width.rem]="30"
30px => [style.width.px]="30"
30% => [style.width.%]="30"
```

Comment: Wow that's cool been with Angular since beta never even know they had that.