# progress bar width from .ts file in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have written a code which is properly rendering the UI, but inside demo.component.html file I am getting an error as "property value expected" and "at-rule or selector expected". I tried changing it to [style.width]="{{d.graph_percentage}}" but it is not working.

demo.component.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of data">
  <td>
   <div class="progress">
     <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuenow="100"
         class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped {{d.graph_color}}"
         role="progressbar"
         style="width: {{d.graph_percentage}} ">
     </div>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

demo.component.ts: It has json as:

```
public data = [{
    "graph_percentage": "10%",
    "graph_color": "bg-danger"
}];
```

here is ss from code editor:

[image: error from code editor]

Comment: Use: `[ngStyle]="{'width': d.graph_precentage}`  source: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484129/5107490

Comment: @ShayD, [style.width.%]="30" this worked but [style.width.%]="{{d.graph_precentage}}", not working. Also I have removed % sign from my json file.

Comment: Hey Thanks, @ShayD, It worked with [style.width.%]="d.graph_percentage"